# XOR ing 3 numbers in php 5.4

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-xor

i have this first bit number

```
36700165
```

and i am trying to XOR these 3 bits out of that first number

```
117440512
```

im doing

```
$bit = 36700165 XOR 0x1000000 XOR 0x2000000 XOR 0x4000000;
```

but it is returning empty when it should be returning

```
3145733
```

EDIT:
this gave me what i want, is there a better way?

```
$bit = 36700165 & ~ 0x1000000 & ~ 0x2000000 & ~ 0x4000000;
$bit = 36700165 & ~ 117440512;
```

Comment: But `117440512 ^ 36700165` is actually `87031813`, and all of this is entirely unclear because it's in decimal so you can't see what's going on. Anyway one does not "XOR out" bits usually, you "AND out" bits. Did you mean to AND with 0xFFFFFF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$bit = 36700165 & ~ 0x1000000 & ~ 0x2000000 & ~ 0x4000000;
$bit = 36700165 & ~ 117440512;
```